# GetElementById does not locate elements currently visible in webbrowser

Tags: javascript, c#, html

I'm trying to automate navigation through a webpage that uses HTML and JavaScript. I'm using C# to do this and have not worked with it for a long time so am rather rusty, this is the best I've managed to come up with (including trying webBrowserEvents2).

What I have so far is attached below. Everything runs ok until the 5th while statement which continues as an infinite loop even though element in question is visible in the web browser.

I've commented-out the 5th while statement and everything below it in the first method and then used the second method to list all the elements in the web browser the have IDs. I've found all the elements listed belong to the previous page even though it is no longer visible.

This issue has not been present in the earlier while statements so I am not sure what the problem could be. I have tried refreshing, updating and invalidating the web browser and this has not worked. What is causing this to happen?

```
    //Start navigation 
    private void goButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Load Login page
        webBrowser1.Navigate(site);
        while (webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("gwt-uid-27") == null) 
        {
            Application.DoEvents();
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Login page loaded");

        //Login
        webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("gwt-uid-27").SetAttribute("value", password);
        webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("gwt-uid-37").InvokeMember("click");
        while (webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("popup_0") == null)
        {
            Application.DoEvents();
        }
        while (webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("popup_0") != null)
        {
            Application.DoEvents();
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Login Successful");

        //Navigate to timesheets page
        webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("gwt-uid-48").InvokeMember("click");
        while (webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("add-time") == null)
        {
            Application.DoEvents();
        }

        //Go to 'Select date' page
        webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("add-time").InvokeMember("click");
        while (webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("gwt-uid-120") == null)
        {
            Application.DoEvents();
        }

        //Enter date
        string date = String.Format("{0:yyyy-M-d}", dateTimePicker);
        webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("gwt-uid-120").SetAttribute("value", date);
        webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("gwt-uid-125").InvokeMember("click");
}

private void secondary_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var v = webBrowser1.Document.All;
        List<string> c = new List<string>();

        foreach (HtmlElement h in v)
        {
            if (h.Id!=null) c.Add(h.Id);    
        }

        Console.WriteLine("done");
    }
```

Since posting this I've written the same method in VBA with no issues whatsoever and can't figure out why.

Comment: Isnt the method `getElementById` and not `GetElementById`?

Comment: I'm using C# to access a webpage that runs in JavaScript and HTML. For C# it is GetElementById.